# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error`:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'`.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.class

This is the exception I got after compiling ***google guava library***.

Here, the issue is some other library is using the same class(issue of duplicacy)

Did all necessary things like listing all the library my project is using( ../gradlew.bat dependencies) but found no duplicate class

*Below my Gradle.*

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'

   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'

  /*Firebase*/

 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'

   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'

  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    /*Header recyclerView*/

 compile 'com.karumi:headerrecyclerview:1.1.0'

 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*Custom snackBar*/

 compile 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
    /*google services*/

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
    /*socket io*/

 compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    /*Map utils library*/

  compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

 compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

 compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this exclude the duplicated file by using below code in your gradle app module

```
android {


  buildTypes {

 }
 packagingOptions {
    exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude  'build-data.properties'
}
```

}

and try this also

```
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2') {
exclude module: 'guava'
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ,Tried this fix earlier not able to sort out

Comment: I am facing this issue on lollipop devices,Marshmallow its working fine.